# Simple Regex phantom matches?

Tags: java, regex

Why does the following Regex return two matches?

Regex: `[^,]*`

Input: `AB`

Output (Two matches):

`|AB|
||`

I am expecting only one match, `AB`

I tried it in a couple of Regex testers, it's not a language specific issue.

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/fjT79V/2

Sample code (Java):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^,]*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("AB");

    while (m.find()) 
        System.out.println("|" + m.group() + "|");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve one match on empty string and one match on 'AB' using the same regex? `+` will not match the empty string. This is part  of a bigger regex: `([^,]*,?)` should have two matches on `AB,CD`, but has 3 matches: `AB`, `CD`, and empty string.

Comment: It should return two matches, but it returns 3: `AB,` and then `CD` and then empty string.

Comment: This answer is not correct, and this question is not the duplicate it is marked.

The correct answer is in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296146/how-to-parse-comma-separated-line-correctly-with-regex

 `[^,]+|(?<=,)`