# How to parse comma separated line correctly with regex

Tags: regex, csv

Trying to parse comma separated line with regex, but getting inconsistent results:

Regex: `([^,]*),?`

The actual value is in match group 1 (excludes the comma).

Expected results:

```
a,,b  -> 3 matches
a,,b, -> 4 matches
a,,,b -> 4 matches
```

The number of matches is the number of commas + 1.

The problem is the regex matches at the end even if there is no comma, so getting:

```
a,,b  -> 4 matches
a,,b, -> 4 matches
```

Both return 4 matches, even though the lines have a different number of values.

**Is it possible to fix the regex so the number of matches is the number of values** (commas + 1) without correcting the results in code?

Comment: Does the language you're using have a regex.Split?

Comment: Use `([^,\v]+|(?<=,))(?=,|$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

It seems your regex is not matching any characters in some locations and working as a sort of assertion (asserting that no character is matched in your group and not followed by a comma `,`, which is perfectly valid according to your regex).

This answer is a *fix* that allows you to match 1 or more of any non-comma `,` character, or an assertion for a zero-width match all-the-while asserting the position as being preceded by a comma `,`.

The best way to go about this would be to split the string on `,` using a string function, but this method also works.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/eBjtpA/2)

```
([^,\v]+|(?<=,))(?=,|$)
```

---

### Explanation

- `([^,\v]+|(?<=,))` Capture either of the following into capture group 1

  - `[^,\v]+` Match one or more of any character not present in the set `,\v`. This matches the comma `,` literally, or vertical whitespace characters `\v` (such as newline characters)
  - `(?<=,)` Match the position where the previous token (using positive lookbehind) is a comma `,`
- `(?=,|$)` Positive lookahead to ensure what follows is either a comma `,` literally or the end of the string `$`

Comment: Thanks, can you please share some knowledge about the lookaheads in this case?

Comment: You’re welcome! The positive look ahead is ensuring what follows the preceding token matches either a comma or the end of the line.